# Antivirus software for iOS and an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

I just started at a new job. The IT manager gave me the task of deploying 50 iPads using JAMF.

Now my manager wants to deploy antivirus software to the iPads. I said huh??

He insists that we push out an antivirus program because the user are going to install malicious apps.

Can you guys help me out?

Are there any antivirus apps for iOS? Any articles I can use to make my case that there isn't a need?

Comment: [This page](https://www.safetydetective.com/recommended2/ios-antivirus/us/) may be helpful for your search.

Comment: I suggest you ask in: https://discussions.apple.com/community/mac_os/mac_os_x_technologies

Comment: See this article. https://www.tomsguide.com/us/iphones-dont-need-antivirus-software,news-23111.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are really working on Jamf MDM and to have centralized AV, then I highly recommend Crowdstrike from Falcon.

Crowdstrike's Lightweight sensor technology is ideal for mobile devices, and CrowdStrike’s cloud-native platform provides the perfect conduit to manage, administer and hunt for data.

More detail on: [Crowdstrike for mobile](https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/crowdstrike-is-the-first-to-bring-endpoint-detection-and-response-edr-to-mobile-devices/)

Go through it and do your research. We are using this for all macOS and iOS devices. It is very light on the end-user. JAMF highly supports scripts as well.